# Instantiate one of many derived classes - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue where I have a number of classes that derive from one Abstract class.

```
public abstract class Bet
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public abstract void LockUpChips();
}
```

I also have a class that is attached to various GameObjects around a scene. It has an enum called BetType:

```
public class BetArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BetType Type;
    public int Number;
    public int NumberTwo;
...
```

A couple of the derived classes:

```
public class PassBet : Bet, IBet
{
    public PassBet(int amt)
    {
        Amount = amt;
    }

    public void Adjudicate()
    {
        int result = GameManager.Instance.DieResults[0] + GameManager.Instance.DieResults[1];
        if (GameManager.Instance.Point == 0)
        {
            switch (result)
            {
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 12:
                    GameManager.Instance.LosingBets.Add(this);
                    break;
                case 7:
                case 11:
                    GameManager.Instance.PlayerMoney += GetPayout();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(result == 7)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.LosingBets.Add(this);
            }
            else if (result == GameManager.Instance.Point)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.PlayerMoney += GetPayout();
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal GetPayout()
    {
        return Amount;
    }

    public override void LockUpChips()
    {
        GameManager.Instance.ClearBetArea(BetType.Pass);
    }
}

public class PlaceBet : Bet, IBet
{
    public int BetNumber { get; set; }

    public PlaceBet(int num, int amt)
    {
        Amount = amt;
        BetNumber = num;
    }

    public void Adjudicate()
    {
        int result = GameManager.Instance.DieResults[0] + GameManager.Instance.DieResults[1];
        if (GameManager.Instance.Point != 0)
        {
            if (result == 7)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.LosingBets.Add(this);
            }
            else if (result == BetNumber)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.PlayerMoney += GetPayout();
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal GetPayout()
    {
        decimal Multiplier = 0m;
        switch (BetNumber)
        {
            case 4:
            case 10:
                Multiplier = (9m / 5m);
                break;
            case 5:
            case 9:
                Multiplier = (7m / 5m);
                break;
            case 6:
            case 8:
                Multiplier = (7m / 6m);
                break;
        }
        return Amount * Multiplier;
    }
    public override void LockUpChips()
    {
        GameManager.Instance.ClearBetArea(BetType.Place);
    }
}
```

I found myself falling into a bad pattern. Later in the BetArea class definition is this:

```
public void Clicked()
{
    switch (Type)
    {
        case BetType.Pass:
            GameManager.Instance.Bets.Add(new PassBet(GameManager.Instance.BetDenomination));
            //do lots of other things
            break;
        case BetType.Place:
            GameManager.Instance.Bets.Add(new PlaceBet(Number, GameManager.Instance.BetDenomination));
            //do lots of other things slightly differently
            break;
...
```

Where GameManager.Instance.Bets is a List (an interface that the derived classes inherit). I want to parameterize this in another method in the BetArea class... I've been trying something like:

```
private void IncreaseOrCreateBet<T>() where T : Bet
    {
        GameManager.Instance.Bets.Add(new T()); // :(
    }
```

...which doesn't do the trick. I'm still getting the hang of polymorphism, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: That last code would also require the `new()` generic type constraint.  You can't invoke a constructor on `T` if you don't know for a fact that `T` will have a constructor, which is what that generic type constraint is for.

Comment: Side note - why doesn't the abstract class `Bet` implements the `IBet` interface? it can have abstract methods that passes the responsibility of actual implementations to it's derived classes.

Comment: Unless each class that inherits from `Bet` has a parameterless constructor, you should stick with your current implementation.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the new() constraint. Unfortunately each derived class has a varying # of params. @Zohar Peled - I probably didn't think of it. Still a little new to c# :)